# Enable Google Assistant in Windows

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to do some automations using Google Assistant. Is it possible to integrate the mobile google assistant app with python? For example if I say open edge in my PC in my mobile and I am able to fetch the same from a python app running on my PC, I can create custom actions based on that. Can anyone help me with how can that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the highest level, Google Assistant is able to be programmed using "Actions on Google".  Actions on Google takes your audio input and drives a service called "Dialog Flow".  Dialog Flow parses your natural language looking for an "intent" (what you are asking for).  When an intent is matched, a "Webhook" can be called to process the request.

If you have an application running on your Windows PC that is listening for an incoming REST request and can process the payload content, then the Webhook specified in Dialog Flow can be used to invoke your Windows application (REST app) that can perform the work.

Wiring all this up does take some skills.  Some good reading to start with would be:

- https://assistant.google.com/
- https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1EXoqvR9VrmWnM9S47SfVA
- https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/

Comment: Thank you. I shall try this out and update you on the progress.

Comment: Hi I now understand the Webhook part, but say if I have to use this from my personal laptop, I do not have a static IP, I cannot call a flask server running on my PC using webhook then, so suppose if I say Robert open Outlook, how can I receive the response from my PC.

Comment: Commonly, the Webhook implementation is hosted in the cloud at a fixed URL.  For example, Google Cloud Functions or Google Cloud Run.  In the vast majority of use cases, Assistant will be invoked by users at any time / any place and hence the fulfillment of that can happen any time.  Users of Assistant would then dedicate a fixed endpoint machine to "handle" the fulfillment.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation..yes i feel Cloud Functions of app engine might solve the purpose...later on the response can be pushed into a local machine using cloud mqtt